# How to clear Redis Database in test environment with fakeredis?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, redis

I would like to clear Redis database on each spec.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`flushdb` clears current database, `flushall` clears all databases.

[flushdb definition](http://redis.io/commands/FLUSHDB)